# Converting Data to Timeseries - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, import, time-series

I have Excel data in the following format

```
Ticker     Date     Price
GOOG       1/1/12    100
GOOG       1/2/12    200
AAPL       1/1/12     50
```

etc.

I would like to convert this to a time series collection (or just a matrix of data) in the following format:

```
Date      GOOG   AAPL   .... (variable number of tickers)
1/1/12     100     50
```

As this would be easier to use in Matlab to do some calculations on it.

The way I've done this in the past, and I dont believe it is the most efficient, was to run a `unique(tickers)` function to check how many tickers we have, then chop off the data accordingly in a for loop. I think this is very inefficient (and ugly) for larger data sets. I was hoping someone would have a better suggestion?

Here's a sample of previous attempts I've done on similar data which assumes the data are sorted by ticker:

```
[uniqueSecurities, uniqueIndex] = unique(Tickers);
numberSecurities = length(uniqueSecurities);
```

The above code would now tell you at which location does a new ticker start (at every uniqueIndex entry).

now assuming there is the same number of observations for each ticker, you can chop off the data in this manner:

```
numberObservations = whatever
j = 0;
for secIndex = 1:numberSecurities   
    NewDataMatrix(:,secIndex) = Prices(j : j + numberObservations);
    j = j + numbrtObservations;
end
```

Now if you have a variable number of observations for each security, instead of jumping by "numberObservations" intervals, you use the `uniqueIndex` I defined above, and, in a similar manner, chop everything with the indices between uniqueIndex(k) and uniqueIndex(k+1).

The reason I'm posting is because I dont believe I am being very efficient, and in addition is there some default MATLAB way to doing this? As I understand, most databases will give me data in the above format (not the best of formats!) and I dont have any control over the format unfortunately.

Comment: Can you still share what you have done so far?

Comment: Added some extra code :)